# When does Node Readable Stream of _read() called

Tags: node.js, stream, node-streams

I create my own readstream. But I want to know when the _read() be called？ If I don't  add `on('data'）` listerner, the _read() will not be called. Why?

```
var data = [{"id":0,"name":"object 0","value":3}],
    Readable = require('stream').Readable,
    util = require('util');

var ReadStream = function() {
    Readable.call(this, {objectMode: true});
    this.data = data;
    this.curIndex = 0;
};
util.inherits(ReadStream, Readable);

ReadStream.prototype._read = function() {
    if (this.curIndex === this.data.length)
        return this.push(null);

    var data = this.data[this.curIndex++];
    //console.log('read: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    this.push(data);
};


var stream = new ReadStream();
stream.on('data', function(record) {
    console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(record));
});

stream.on('end', function() {
    console.log('done111');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I don't add on('data'） listerner, the _read() will not be called. Why?

The stream is paused. Assuming you are using a recent version of node.

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_two_modes

> All Readable streams begin in paused mode but can be switched to flowing mode in one of the following ways:
>
> Adding a 'data' event handler.
>
> Calling the stream.resume() method.
>
> Calling the stream.pipe() method to send the data to a Writable.

BTW, to create a readable, check [noms](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/noms) or [mississippi.from](https://github.com/maxogden/mississippi#from)

Comment: adding a 'data' event handler will switch to flowing mode? where is the source code? I also found it was related to process.nextTick?

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/be68b68d4863f0d389cc46fdf6f1cbcd1b241d0a/lib/_stream_readable.js#L677